# Powershell script to remove Notepad++ and Chrome from remote servers

Tags: powershell

I need with PS script

1. Pull server content from the input file (servers.txt or csv). (hostname). ( this is done)
2. Pull the application list from the input file (programlist.txt or csv). (app list). (this is done)
3. Script needs to be able to backup the existing state (i.e. config & registry settings at a minimum) in regards listed application.
4. Fail gracefully (with try/catch blocks)
5. It should be able to revert back to its previous state if anything should go wrong. 6. Generate output file with results (if failed, if completed successfully )

Step 1,2, 4 and 6 is completed
Step 3 and 5 is missing.  Can you help me with write missing PS code for step 3 and 5?

**# Define paths for input files**

$serversFile = "C:\temp\servers.txt" # Replace with your servers input file

$applicationsFile = "C:\temp\programlist.txt" # Replace with your applications input file

**# Define the path for the output log**

$outputLog = "C:\temp\uninstall_log.txt"

**# Loop through servers from input file**

$servers = Get-Content $serversFile

foreach ($server in $servers) {

try {

**# Connect to the server**

Write-Host "Connecting to $server..."

**# Use Invoke-Command to run the uninstall script on the remote server**

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -ScriptBlock {

param (

$applicationsFile,

$outputLog

)

**# Function to backup application settings (registry, config, etc.)**

function Backup-ApplicationSettings {

****# Implement the backup logic here**
**# Example: Backup registry settings****

}

**# Function to uninstall applications**

function Uninstall-Applications {

param (

$applicationsFile,

$outputLog

)

$applications = Get-Content $applicationsFile

foreach ($app in $applications) {

**# Backup application settings before uninstalling**

Backup-ApplicationSettings

**# Uninstall the application
**# Example: Uninstall using PowerShell or a command line tool like WMIC**
**# Check if the uninstallation was successful****

if ($?) {

Write-Output "Uninstalled $app on $($env:COMPUTERNAME)" | Out-File -Append $outputLog

}

else {

Write-Output "Failed to uninstall $app on $($env:COMPUTERNAME)" | Out-File -Append $outputLog

}

}

}

**# Call the function to uninstall applications**

Uninstall-Applications -applicationsFile $applicationsFile -outputLog $outputLog

} -ArgumentList $applicationsFile, $outputLog

}

catch {

**# Handle errors gracefully**

Write-Output "Error connecting to ${server}: $_" | Out-File -Append $outputLog

}

}

This is what I was trying to achieve

The script will need to be able to back up the existing state (i.e. config & registry settings at a minimum) , fail gracefully (with try/catch blocks)  , and it should be able to revert back to its previous state if anything should go wrong.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Could you please go back, edit your question once again and [format your code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) properly? Thanks in advance. 

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).